# Intercept/stop ASP.NET Identity unauthorized redirect for authenticated users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

ASP.NET Identity issues a **302 Found** response, redirecting to the Login page for all unauthorized requests, including authenticated requests with insufficient permissions. It's a confusing user experience to redirect an authenticated user to a login page.

How can I intercept/stop/cancel this redirect for authenticated users and issue a **403 Forbidden** response (and therefore show my custom 403 page) instead? Unauthenticated users should continue to see the standard behavior.

I've tried adding a simple custom Owin Middleware before and after the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` but could not figure out how to identify an unauthorized request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a custom Authentication Filter with similar code:

```
public abstract class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }
        //Intercept results where person is authetnicated but still doesn't have permissions
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Sorry, you are logged in but you have attempted to access a page that you don't have permissions to.";

            //TODO need to set up a route that points to your custom page, call that route RestrictedAccess
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("RestrictedAccess", new RouteValueDictionary());
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And then instead of `[Authorise]` you need to apply `[MyAuthorise]` attribute to your controllers.

Comment: This is actually similar to what I'm currently doing for MVC actions, except I am returning a 403 response for authenticated users instead of redirecting to a restricted access page. I was hoping for a one-place solution instead of having to remember to always use the custom attribute instead of the default one.

Comment: Afraid I have not found anything better than that. I'll keep watching this thread if alternatives appear.